# JavaFX drop down button

Tags: java, javafx, imagebutton

How can I create a "Drop down button" in JavaFX?

So far i was using a `ChoiceBox` for the purpose , now that I have to assign an image to the `ChoiceBox`,

> ChoiceBox.setGraphic() // is not available as like `Buttons`

So I am planning to change it to a drop down button. So that i can set an icon to it.

Am using `SceneBuilder` for designing UI.

No help in searching how to create a drop down button using JavaFX.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want either, but maybe a [SplitMenuButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitMenuButton.html) is what you want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not have to store the selection like in a `ChoiceBox` you can use for example the [`MenuButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) control.

> MenuButton is a button which, when clicked or pressed, will show a
>   ContextMenu.

A `MenuButton` has the [`graphicProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty) mentioned by you as its base class is `Labeled`.

**Simple example**

```
final Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("cross_red.png").toExternalForm(), 20, 20, true, true);
MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Don't touch this");
menuButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
menuButton.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Really"), new MenuItem("Do not"));
```

*This will produce a button like:*

[image]

**Note:** If you need the button also to act like a real button, you can switch from `MenuButton` to [`SplitMenuButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitMenuButton.html). The only difference is that the control field is splitted into a button part and a drop down part (so you can assign an action also for the header):

> The SplitMenuButton, like the MenuButton is closely associated with
>   the concept of selecting a MenuItem from a menu. Unlike MenuButton,
>   the SplitMenuButton is broken into two pieces, the "action" area and
>   the "menu open" area.
>
> If the user clicks in the action area, the SplitMenuButton will act
>   similarly to a Button, firing whatever is associated with the
>   ButtonBase.onAction property.