# Add Menu To Top of Button in Java FX

Tags: java, button, javafx

I am trying to get the effect of a drop down menu with arbitrary contents in a JavaFX button. Here is what I have so far:

```
// I'm using a popup, but that isn't owned by the main window
button1.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    try {
        VBox popup = (VBox) FXMLLoader.load(Popup.class.getResource("Popup.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(popup, 50, 100);
        Bounds boundsInScreen = button1.localToScreen(button1.getBoundsInLocal());
        dialog.setX(boundsInScreen.getMinX());
        dialog.setY(boundsInScreen.getMinY() - 100); // This isn't dynamic, so it's bad
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

I was hoping there was a nice way to bundle the button and its associated popup, (which is basically any arbitrary form) in a way where I don't have to keep track of the size of the popup.

Comment: Wouldn't be a button like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163881/javafx-drop-down-button/39164430#39164430 sufficient?

Comment: No, the problem is that I am not trying to show a menu. I'm trying to show a form with check boxes, text fields, etc. So the form should behave like a menu in terms of how it is shown and hidden, but the contents aren't menu items.